# Numpy: multiplying with NaN values without using nan_to_num

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was able to optimise some operations in my program quite a bit using `numpy`. When I profile a run, I noticed that most of the time is spent in `numpy.nan_to_num`. I'd like to improve this even further.

The sort of calculations occurring are multiplication of two arrays for which one of the arrays could contain `nan` values. I want these to be treated as zeros, but I can't initialise the array with zeros, as `nan` has a meaning later on and can't be set to 0. Is there a way of doing multiplications (and additions) with `nan` being treated as zero?

From the `nan_to_num` docstring, I can see a new array is produced which may explain why it's taking so long.

> Replace nan with zero and inf with finite numbers.
>
> Returns an array or scalar replacing Not a Number (NaN) with zero,...

A function like [`nansum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) for arbitrary arithmetic operations would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's some example data:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
a[a < 0.1] = np.nan    # set some random values to nan
b = np.ones_like(a)
```

One option is to use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to set the value of the result to 0 wherever one of your arrays is equal to NaN:

```
result = np.where(np.isnan(a), 0, a * b)
```

If you have to do several operations on an array that contains NaNs, you might consider using [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html), which provide a more general method for dealing with missing or invalid values:

```
masked_a = np.ma.masked_invalid(a)

result2 = masked_a * b
```

Here, `result2` is another `np.ma.masked_array` whose `.mask` attribute is set according to where the NaN values were in `a`. To convert this back to a normal `np.ndarray` with the masked values replaced by 0s, you can use the `.filled()` method, passing in the fill value of your choice:

```
result_filled = result2.filled(0)

assert np.all(result_filled == result)
```

Comment: This `masked_invalid` and subsequent `filled` approach takes actually longer than `nan_to_num` (at least in my use case).

Comment: OK, what about using `np.where` then? Can you give a realistic test case?

Comment: Yep. Forgot to mention it. That actually works quite well (and faster).

Comment: Would you care to expand on what `np.where` in your context does? I have a construct such as `(p * np.nan_to_num(s)).sum(axis=3, out=p)` and tried to convert it into `p = np.where(s, 0, s * p).sum(axis=3)` but this doesn't seem to give the same results. Is my transformation correct?

Comment: The syntax is `np.where(condition, val_where_true, val_where_false)`. In your example you want your resulting array to have a value of 0 wherever `s` is equal to NaN, and `s * p` wherever `s` is not equal to NaN. Hence: `np.where(np.isnan(s), 0, s * p)`.

Comment: I see what the problem is - I forgot the `np.isnan(s)`. Thanks for the explanation (+1).

Comment: Shouldn't `np.where(np.isnan(s) & (s==0), 0, s * p)` lead to a further speedup? In my case, this gives different results than before...

Comment: It's unnecessary: where `s == 0` then `(s * p) == 0`. If you wanted to go down this route then you would have to use `|` (bitwise or) rather than `&`. At the moment your condition can never be satisfied, since it isn't possible for `s` to be equal to both NaN and 0.